# Swing frames overlapping after certain button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

After doing my log in page and clicking the log in button, my second frame comes up on top of the log in page where you can still see the components hiding below. Why isn't it gone after clicking on the log in button?

Here's my code:

```
public void showLogIn(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    logInPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,4,4));  
    logInPanel.add(label1);
    logInPanel.add(username);
    logInPanel.add(label2);
    logInPanel.add(password);
    add(logInPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(loginBut, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    loginBut.addActionListener(this);
}

public void showAdminForm(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400,300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    label3.setText("Logged in as: " + username.getText());
    add(label3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    buttonPanel.add(createRoom);
    buttonPanel.add(deleteRoom);
    buttonPanel.add(createLect);
    buttonPanel.add(deleteLect);
    buttonPanel.add(showLect);
    buttonPanel.add(logOut);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

In the action listener, I implemented something like calling the `showAdminForm();` but my log in form remains there. Is there a way I don't have to do it with `CardLayout`?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) *"Is there a way I don't have to do it with cardlayout?"* What have you got against using `CardLayout`? 3) `setVisible(true)` should be the last thing that is done. 4) Swap `setSize(..)` for `pack()`

Comment: So there's no way to hide the components in showLogIn() without using CardLayout?

Comment: ***What have you got against using `CardLayout`?***  In case you misunderstood, I did not ask that question for my own amusement.  I expect an answer, and will get one before I consider answering any further questions.

Comment: CardLayout is more complicated, IMO. And I myself prefer BorderLayout because it gives me more positioning feel.

Comment: It's okay, I've learned to use CardLayout. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  Note that we can (and typically do) use more than one layout per GUI.  E.G. A `CardLayout` might flip between two components, one of which is a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`.